# How construct morphia model for this json?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am developing application where I must store work week schedule. 
`workSchedule` consist of 7 days (array), each day consist array, and this array consist another array where I store startTime and endTime since midnight.

I tried with `List<List<Integer[]>> workSchedule`

With `List<List<List<Integer>>> workSchedule`

With `Integer[][][] workSchedule`

But nothing worked. It typically says `BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys`

How construct right model? Please, any suggestions.

Updated.

Below my model from mongodb.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "579dfa208f9c311d327e478a"
  },
  "status": "approved",
  "ratingMinus": 0,
  "ratingPlus": 0,
  "lat": 55.767166134693,
  "lng": 37.59573578997,
  "address": "Большая Садовая улица, дом 16, сооружение 1",
  "type": "public",
  "price": 0,
  "isFree": true,
  "workSchedule": [
    [
      [
        28800,
        72000
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        28800,
        72000
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        28800,
        72000
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        28800,
        72000
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        28800,
        72000
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        28800,
        72000
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        28800,
        72000
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2016-07-31T13:16:16.454Z"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2016-07-31T13:16:16.454Z"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "location": [
    37.59573578997,
    55.767166134693
  ]
}
```

And here JAVA properties:

```
@Id
private ObjectId id;
private String status;
private int ratingMinus;
private int ratingPlus;
private String address;
@Reference
private WcUser createdBy;
@Reference
private WcUser updatedBy;
private Date createdAt;
private Date updatedAt;
private String routeDetails;
private String type;
private List<List<List<Integer>>> workSchedule;
private boolean isFree;
private int price;
@Indexed(IndexDirection.GEO2D)
private Double[] location;
```

And I try to get data from mongo as follow:

```
List<WcInstance> wcs = mongoConnectionManager
        .getDatastore()
        .find(WcInstance.class)
        .field("location")
        .near(longitude, latitude, 3 / 111.12)
        .limit(100)
        .asList();
```

And it works if I comment out `workSchedule` property and doesn't if not.

Error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [size]`

Answer (score 0):

`List<List<List<Integer>>> workSchedule` should work.  Please post the actual model class and how you tried to use it.  There's probably some nuance there you're missing.

Comment: What version of morphia are you using?  that works for me with 1.3.0.

Comment: But 1.3.0 haven't not released yet. I use 1.2.1

Comment: I have tried with 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT and it says `org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: The DBOBbject does not contain a className key.  Determining entity type is impossible.`

Comment: Can anybody help?)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an answer, the reason why I got this error was because I included `@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)` in the (sub)classes.

Removing it worked, and also, using Gson can filter out the stored class name when converting back to JSON.